# convert JS object to Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects as below

```
[
  {
    Instance: 'USM 1',
    performance:
      '&lt;DanPac_A&gt;.&lt;Daniel.DanOPCHub&gt;.&lt;A Session.Perfomance&gt;',
    agc: '&lt;DanPac_A&gt;.&lt;Daniel.DanOPCHub&gt;.&lt;A Session.AGC&gt;',
    snr: '&lt;DanPac_A&gt;.&lt;Daniel.DanOPCHub&gt;.&lt;A Session.SNR&gt;',
    sos: '&lt;DanPac_A&gt;.&lt;Daniel.DanOPCHub&gt;.&lt;A Session.SNR&gt;',
    flowvel: '&lt;DanPac_A&gt;.&lt;Daniel.DanOPCHub&gt;.&lt;A Session.SNR&gt;',
  },
];
```

I need to take `Instance` out as a key and use its value as a property instead.

expected output

```
[
  {
    'USM 1': [
      {
        performance: 'value',
        agc: 'value',
        // ...
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

any idea how to take it out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Array::map()`:

```js
const arr = [{
    "Instance": "USM 1",
    "performance": "&lt;DanPac_A&gt;.&lt;Daniel.DanOPCHub&gt;.&lt;A Session.Perfomance&gt;",
    "agc": "&lt;DanPac_A&gt;.&lt;Daniel.DanOPCHub&gt;.&lt;A Session.AGC&gt;",
    "snr": "&lt;DanPac_A&gt;.&lt;Daniel.DanOPCHub&gt;.&lt;A Session.SNR&gt;",
    "sos": "&lt;DanPac_A&gt;.&lt;Daniel.DanOPCHub&gt;.&lt;A Session.SNR&gt;",
    "flowvel": "&lt;DanPac_A&gt;.&lt;Daniel.DanOPCHub&gt;.&lt;A Session.SNR&gt;"
}];

const mapped = arr.map(({Instance, ...item}) => ({[Instance]: [item]}));
    
console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: you can simply destructure `.map(({Instance, ...item })=> ({[Instance]: [item]});`